# Convert a 40 pin female 2.54mm pitch header to screw terminal blocks

Tags: header, screw-terminal

I have the following board and I need to convert the 2 row 40 pin female header to screw terminal blocks. The pitch is 2.54 mm both horizontally and vertically. I've looked at ones such as this https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10571, but I was wondering if there was a 2 row solution somewhere out there?

I've been searching for a couple of days and any pointers would be helpful. Here's the board:

[image]

Comment: Why would you *want* to do this? I can think of very few applications where a device which is supplied wth a 0.1" pin header/socket fits into a application where screw terminals are used.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to form a robust connection between this board and a micro-controller, but I want to avoid soldering. If there's anything besides screw terminals, I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You could make an adapter board which would have

- male pins to mate with your existing 2x20 female
- screw terminals of any style you like
- mounting holes, which match the mounting holes on your motherboard.  This would make the construction more robust.
- other components of your design

I haven't seen screw terminal with the right pitch to mate with (or replace) your female 2x20 connector.  I doubt that such screw terminal connector exists.

Comment: How hard would this be to do given I'm a complete newbie to this? (just learned how to solder last week). And if I only need to use about 6 out of the 40 pins, is there anything that can form a robust wire connection to a micro-controller besides a screw terminal?

Answer (score 0):

What you are after is something like this:

[image: IDC Breakout]

It is called an IDC breakout board, and can be found in quite a few places, including the usual [Chinese sources](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/IDC40-IDE-calbe-IDC40-to-terminal-block-breakout-board-idc-40-connector-PLC-relay-adapter-IDC40/32871723614.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.15.277d3c5cwuWO9z&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_4_10065_10068_319_10059_10884_317_10887_10696_321_322_10084_453_10083_454_10103_10618_10307_537_536_10902,searchweb201603_70,ppcSwitch_0&algo_expid=615199f9-dfab-4481-9f52-dab72ccc6d14-2&algo_pvid=615199f9-dfab-4481-9f52-dab72ccc6d14)

To connect the female end of the cable to the one on the board you can just use a wirewrap male header, which has long enough terminals to connect into both plugs.
With a bit of luck, you might be able to plug your board directly into the breakout board.